# Retrieving the word from the mouse cursor position

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I am trying to retrieve the word from the RichTextEdit control where the mouse cursor currently focusing on

Is there any specific event in RichTextEdit that I can use to retrieve the word?

Thanks

regards,
Balan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not talking about Devexpress RichTextEdit , then i think you can use the carret position as it is shown here

[Problem with finding the next word in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603764/problem-with-finding-the-next-word-in-richtextbox)

and also use the MouseDown event to use it .

also this maybe helps too

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.onmouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx